# How to display mp4 file format with Nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following code on my component and the video is stored under `/public`

```
<video autoPlay loop>
    <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I have the next.config.js as followed

```
module.exports = withPlugins( // I use next-compose-plugins
  [
    ...some plugin
  ],
  withVideos(nextConfig), // I use next-videos
)
```

I cant seem to have my video play at all, and I got the following error as `206 Partial Content`. The file video I have is only 180kB.
Anyone know the solution to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't from Nextjs. The video works on Safari, but not Chrome and Firefox. The only thing I had to solve it is compress the video and allow the server to handle content range